# Kotlin Mock Spring boot test can't compile

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

So I have the following test

```
@Test
    fun `when save claims is called with email saved to that profile` () {
        //arrange
        given(profileRepository.findProfileByEmail(anyString())).willAnswer { daoProfile }
        given(patientRepository.findById(anyInt())).willAnswer { Optional.of(daoPatient) }
        given(claimRepository.saveAll(anyList())).willAnswer { mutableListOf(daoClaim) }

        //act
        val result = claimService.saveClaimsForEmail(listOf(dtoClaim), "Test@test.test")

        //assert
        assert(result != null)
        assert(result?.isNotEmpty() ?: false)
        verify(claimRepository).saveAll(anyList())
    }
```

The line `given(claimRepository.saveAll(anyList())).willAnswer { mutableListOf(daoClaim) }` gives the folowing error

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression
File being compiled at position: (217,71) in /Users/archer/Work/masterhealth/master_billing/src/test/kotlin/com/masterhealthsoftware/master_billing/data/service/ClaimServiceTest.kt
The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$typeMappingConfiguration$1.processErrorType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:113)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error type encountered: (???..???) (FlexibleTypeImpl).
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$typeMappingConfiguration$1.processErrorType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:113)
```

When the line is removed, it compiles but the test fails for obvious reasons.

claimRespoitory is annotated @MockBean at the top of the test class, and is a JpaInterface. Line 217 is the start of the function. I've also trie using `when` and other various willReturn or willAnswer....

Any idea why?

Comment: This looks like a kotlin compiler bug. Have you tried reporting it and/or using a different compiler version?

Comment: No I have not, I'll take a look at that today. I assumed I'm doing something wrong first.

Comment: Are You using latest kotlin compiler?

Comment: I tried it with 1.3.71

Comment: I'm starting to think this problem comes from mocking JpaRepository methods. I'm trying a mock on repository.findAll and getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when using Mockito `any()`. Changing it to `ArgumentMatchers.any(YourClass::class.java))` solved the compilation error, there is a deprecated `ArgumentMatchers.anyListOf(YourClass::class.java)` that might do the job.

Comment: so it's not the any matchers. anyList() works fine. I just found out from trying to mock something else that it's trouble when mocking JpaRepository methods. I have a findAll() that I tried to mock and got the same error

Comment: Could you explain a little more?. I'm mocking `findAll()`, `findById(ArgumentMatchers.anyLong())`, `findByLastName(ArgumentMatchers.anyStirng())` and the one mentioned in the answer. Using `JpaRepository` and `ReactiveCrudRepository` and I'm not getting any compile error.  Thx!